# Using the static methods of Validation class in table validator

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

How can I use for example [Ip Address](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_ip) validation in my table. 
I read the [this doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules) and [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#core-validation-rules) but not found the code example to do that.

Comment: That's less CakePHP related, but more of a "_how does PHP work_" type of question, isn't it?

Comment: I found it thanks for you comment @ndm

Comment: @ndm anyway you may didn't understand my question or I didnt explane it well,  if you see the answer bellow you will see it related to "How CakePHP" works

Comment: Your question sounds more like "_how to access a static class method_", hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
    $validator->provider('validation', 'Cake\Validation\Validation');
    $validator->add('ip', 'validation', [
        'rule' => ['ip'],
        'message' => 'IP address is not correct.',
        'provider' => 'validation'
    ]);
```

Comment: The `Cake\Validation\Validation` class is [**the default rules provider**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#adding-validation-providers), adding it manually should not be required, ie using the `ip` rule works out of the box by default, unless you have additionally fiddled with the validator but haven't shown here, which makes the question not overly helpful for future readers, as the problem is not reproducable.

Comment: can you provide me a code that provide this IP validation as a best practice in a separate answer

Comment: I think he's saying it should be exactly what you've posted, except without the call to `$validator->provider` or including `'provider' => 'validation'` in the `add` call. You only need those if you're using a non-default provider.